# How to exclude weekends and holidays dates and find an expected date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, recursive-query

I am working on a task where I have 2 tables. i.e, `tickets` and `holidays`.

Now I also have the number of days to complete the tickets. Now I need to find the expected date by excluding holidays(specified in the `holidays` table) and `weekends`.

Now I can able to find a date using `ticket created date` and `days to complete the ticket`. But unable to calculate the expected due date by removing holidays and weekends.

If ticket expected due date falls under holidays or weekends, we need to shift the expected due date ahead.

And after that we need to compare `ticket_closed_date` and `expected_due_date`.

If `ticket_closed_date <= expected_due_date` then need to return `isSlaMet` as `YES`. Else need to return `isSlaMet` as `NO`.

**Tickets Table**

[image]

**Holidays Table**

[image]

**Example:** Generally if a ticket is created on `2nd October,2020` and its days to complete is `3`, then the expected due date would be, `5th October` and we have a holiday, `5th October`. But there are 1 holiday and 2 weekends in between ticket created date and expected due date. i.e, `3rd, 4th and 5th of October` . So we need to extend the expected due date by `3 days`(because 2 weekends + 1 Holiday). i.e, `8th October`. Ticket is closed on `9th October`.

Then we need to compare `ticket closed date(9th october)` and `expected due date(8th October)` and return `isSlaMet` as `YES`.

**Expected Input**

```
Tickets Table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tid         createdAt         apply_sla    ticket_closed_date     days_to_complete
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100    2020-10-02 00:00:00        1       2020-10-09 00:00:00           3       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       
Holidays Table
----------------------------------------------
id        holiday_date          end_date
----------------------------------------------
20         2020-10-05          2020-10-05
----------------------------------------------

Along with the above holiday, we need to exclude Weekends.
```

**Expected Output**

```
Tickets Table
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tid       createdAt     apply_sla    ticket_closed_date   days_to_complete   expected_due_date    completedIn   isSlaMet
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100  2020-10-02 00:00:00    1       2020-10-09 00:00:00             3        2020-10-08 00:00:00      4           NO
  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the query I have been using so far.

```
    SELECT 
        `t`.`tid`, `t`.`createdAt`, `t`.`days_to_complete`,
        `t`.`ticket_closed_date`,`holidays`.`holiday_date`,
        `holidays`.`end_date`, `t.apply_sla`,
        IF(ISNULL(`t`.`ticket_closed_date`),
            NULL,
            IF((`t`.`apply_sla` = 1),
                IF(((CAST(`t`.`createdAt` AS DATE) + INTERVAL (`t`.`days_to_complete` + 1) DAY) BETWEEN `holidays`.`holiday_date` AND `holidays`.`end_date`),
                    IF((CAST(`t`.`ticket_closed_date` AS DATE) <= (`holidays`.`end_date` + INTERVAL `t`.`days_to_complete` DAY)),
                        'YES',
                        'NO'),
                    IF((CAST(`t`.`ticket_closed_date` AS DATE) <= (`t`.`createdAt` + INTERVAL (`t`.`days_to_complete` + 1) DAY)),
                        'YES',
                        'NO')),
                IF(((TO_DAYS(`t`.`ticket_closed_date`) - TO_DAYS(`t`.`createdAt`)) > (`t`.`days_to_complete` + 1)),
                    'NO',
                    'YES')
            )
        ) AS `isSlaMet`
    FROM
        (`tickets` `t`
        LEFT JOIN `holidays` ON (((CAST(`t`.`createdAt` AS DATE) + INTERVAL (`t`.`days_to_complete` + 1) DAY) BETWEEN `holidays`.`holiday_date` AND `holidays`.`end_date`)))
    ORDER BY `t`.`tid` DESC;
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sample data in pictures is not useful. Replace with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And show desired output for provided sample data.

Comment: I can only refer you again to my original comment

Comment: *I have added sample data* I tell that sample data must be a combination of CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO scripts. And now look at "Expected Input" provided...

Comment: Are weekends in the holidays table?  That would much simplify the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, No, weekends are not stored in holidays. Need to calculate using normal calender logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complicated that it may seem. The simplest approach may be brute force: enumerate all days between the creation and closure date of the ticket with a recursive CTE (available in MySQL 8.0 only), then filter out the weekends and holidays to count the number of SLA days:

```
with recursive cte_tickets as (
    select tid, created_at as dt, ticket_closed_date
    from tickets 
    where apply_sla = 1
    union all
    select tid, dt + interval 1 day, ticket_closed_date
    from cte_tickets
    where dt < ticket_closed_date
)
select t.*, 
    t.created_at 
        + interval (t.days_to_complete + sum(weekday(dt) in (5, 6) or h.holiday_date is not null)) day
        as expected_due_date,    
    count(*) - sum(weekday(dt) in (5, 6) or h.holiday_date is not null) - 1 completed_in,
    t.ticket_closed_date <= t.created_at 
        + interval (t.days_to_complete + sum(weekday(dt) in (5, 6) or h.holiday_date is not null)) day
        as is_sla_met
from tickets t
inner join cte_tickets ct on ct.tid = t.tid
left join holidays h on ct.dt between h.holiday_date and h.end_date
group by t.tid
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=531e8710683d0830ca7572e94688b045)**:

```
tid | created_At          | apply_sla | ticket_closed_date  | days_to_complete | expected_due_date   | completed_in | is_sla_met
--: | :------------------ | :-------- | :------------------ | ---------------: | :------------------ | -----------: | ---------:
100 | 2020-10-02 00:00:00 | 1         | 2020-10-09 00:00:00 |                3 | 2020-10-08 00:00:00 |            4 |          0
```

Comment: Hi @GMB, How to handle weekends at ```sum(weekday(dt) in (5, 6)``` if  there are multiple weekends? I mean there will be no fixed weekends. If days to complete is 15, there would be multiple weekends in between. Then how to handle that dynamically?

Comment: Thanks @GMB, everything is working fine. But I have a small doubt. I've added a new ticket and holidays in demo code. All other records are correct but when I added holidays for 3 days, the resultant ```expected_closed_date```` is showing 1 day less.

Comment: Hi @GMB, we are not using MySQL Version 8 or above. Now its not working. How to solve this issue in prior to version 8.0? I Hope you understand.

Comment: @Aravind: solving such problem in MySQL 5.x will be challenging. I would recommend upgrading...