# Pulling work day within a range of dates with MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table full of different projects and the date ranges those projects are in process
I need to duplicate each project based on every day that it is being worked on.

I have gotten this to work for the most part but I am not sure if there is a better way this seems a little messy

First I created a date range that will meet the needs of all the projects

```
    left join (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, nbr - 1, '01/01/2020') as 'The_date'
            FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
    FROM sys.columns c
  ) nbrs
  WHERE nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/10/2020', '12/30/2030')) as dd
  on cast(dd.The_date as date) >= cast(start_date as date)
  and cast(dd.The_date as date) <= cast(end_date as date) 
  and datename(weekday,dd.The_date) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
```

the `start_date` and `end_date` on the date range fields are for each project.

Then in order to limit only to days of the week i added the last line to my join.

`and datename(weekday,dd.The_date) in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')`

This seems to work okay, but it does not take any holidays into consideration.

is there a better way to put something like this together?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help us help you. However, what it *really* seems like you want/need is a calendar table.

Comment: Yes - a calendar table where you can also record holidays and any other "non-work" dates. Just search "sql server calendar table".

Comment: I think this solution can help u
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64230578/how-to-exclude-weekends-and-holidays-dates-and-find-an-expected-date-in-mysql

Comment: Okay, yes I think that makes sense to add a calendar table to the database, I was hoping i was just missing a built in function that would be able to make those distinctions for me. Thank you for the comments :-)